# How to change the GETPIVOTDATA() dynamically

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have two formulas like below:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Values",'Input Data'!$A$4,"State",Q42,"Route",$S$1,"STAT_COMB",$G$37,"SHA",$G$35)
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Values",'Input Data'!$A$4,"State",Q42,"Route",$S$1,"STAT_COMB",$G$37)
```

The main difference in the second formula is, I'm not considering the "SHA" parameter. To consider this or not depends on another cell value. I can write an if condition to pick the formula accordingly. But the problem is I have another situation like this:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Values",'Input Data'!$A$4,"Route",Q42,"STAT_COMB",$G$37)
```

Here, I'm not considering the "State" and "SHA" parameter which depends on a respective different cells whether to consider or not.

Similarly each [Field],[Item] Pair in the formula depends on respecitve different cells to include them or not.

Writing too many if conditions will make the formula cumbersome. So, I'm wondering if there is any way to dynamically omit the [Field],[Item] pairs in the formula.

I could've used INDIRECT inside the getpivotdata() but INDIRECT fetches only a single value but I need a pair of values for each parameter.

Comment: Allocating Two columns for Field & Item and allowing the users to select required fields from the DropDown List for example 10 rows of data.  The same can be looped from excel vba and a single If() condition will check for empty cells and the same will repeat for rest of the loops.

Comment: Why don't you try putting the conditions in another cell (comparisons) and then use indirect on those comparisons for the pivot table ?  Or use AND(condition1, condition2) to do more comparisons

Comment: @Pramod Have you reviewed my answer?  If my answer doesn't work -- I'd like the feedback so that we can either refine the answer or move on.

Comment: @NicholasPatton I've seen your answer.. Your answer is good but doesn't apply to my scenario as which one to pick and which to not will change and I can't use separate cells to identify them. My solution is only to use multiple IF conditions as the case is much complex to explain.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could figure out...but it isn't necessarily pretty...

The challenge here is that you can't (to my knowledge and without VBA) dynamically change which overloaded GETPIVOTDATA function you are using in a cell.  So we need to pick 1 function.  In this example, here's my function:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of hello",INDIRECT(K2),M1,O1,M2,O2,M3,O3,M4,O4)
```

I've picked an overload that specifies 4 [field,item] pairs.

Now I set up my worksheet like this...

[image]

You see -- for this example, I only want to use 2 [field,item] pairs -- so I just copy the parameters to fill in the remaining 2 pairs in the overloaded function.  Excel still calculates the GETPIVOTDATA function correctly since I really have only specified 2 unique [field,item] pairs.

Does this get you far enough towards your goal?